# multiple partitions in windows 8 system causing confusion. Need to install Ubuntu

Tags: linux, partitioning

I have no idea where to install Mangaka Moe as there doesn't seem to be enough room in the partition.

I have multiple partitions, some of which seem unnecessary to me. 260 MB OEM Partition 1.44 GB Recovery Partition 260 MB EFI System Partition 666.65 Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition 350 MB Recovery Partition 26.11 GB Recovery Partition 3.46 GB Unallocated

I think there is bloatware from Sony Vaio. I don't know if I should use disk management in windows 8 to move the unallocated to the 666.65 GB (NFTS). I am at a loss here. Please help!

Comment: Can you use the SONY recovery software to create a recovery DVD/set of DVDs? If you're going to mess with your partitions (and you don't know what you're doing) you need a complete backup of everything before you begin! It's easiere to recover your computer from a DVD/set of DVDs in the event you destroy the recovery partition and leave yourself up the creak... with a bill from SONY for new recovery media and a number of weeks wait for it to be delivered...

Answer (score 0):

Just open windows partition manager. If it doesn't allow you to edit the partitions as you need them, do a Google search for "linux partition manager live usb" and create a bootable USB using an ISO or IMG file. Then boot into that and have fun partitioning without restriction.

Comment: Without knowing what partitions to delete, this advice is rather dangerous. Some of those partitions are necessary, and manufacturers can put necessary stuff on any partition they like, so which partition(s) can be deleted will be very system-specific knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which supports up to 128 partitions by default. Some of the partitions you mentioned are necessary for system operation. Others were added by Sony and are needed by Sony's tools, such as the recovery partitions, that are used for (drum roll, please) recovery operations. Many of these partitions are likely to be small by modern disk standards. The point of all this is that you should focus on the disk space used rather than the number of partitions. Unlike in the old MBR days, you're not limited to just four primary partitions.

That said, you can obtain Windows installation media from Microsoft legally and for free, as described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/) (among other places; try a Web search). Using such media, you can wipe your disk and install everything from scratch in a "generic" way, eliminating any OEM bloatware that might be present. This will reduce the partition count, but the main benefit is in removing bloatware *within* the partitions. Of course, this action will wipe all your data, including any personal files, so you should back up such files before you re-install Windows.